# Angular: Recorrer objeto y comparar el intervalo de dos horas

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, objeto

He preguntado ya varias veces de este tema, pero no llego a la solución, si hay alguien allí que me quiera explicar le agradecería, llevo intentandolo una semana yo sola, pero por más esfuerzo y dedicación no me sale, por eso vengo aquí:

**Contexto**

Yo tengo un calendario en `mat-calender`, cuando yo le doy clic a alguno de los dias habilitados en este abre un `button` que esta siendo recorriedo por un `*ngFor` y que obtiene la variable que almacena la función que itera un objeto de arreglos. Este objeto de arreglo tiene dentro una hora de inicio y final, ambos horas son comparadas y se obtiene el intervalo de estas.

El resultado es algo asi:

7:00 AM - 8:00 AM - 9:00 AM ... 4:00 PM

Y el objeto que estoy iterando es el siguiente

```
slots: [
   0: 
     {
       slot: "07:00-08:00"
       available: true
       count: 0
       end: "2021-12-23T08:00:00-06:00"
       start: "2021-12-23T07:00:00-06:00"
     }
]
```

Donde:

slot: es un rango horario diferencial de una hora, lo que quiere decir que su viene en este objeto 6 arreglos de las 7:00 a las 4:00 hay una hora de diferencia hasta llegar a la últimahora

available: Nos dice si esa hora esta disponible

end y start: Nos muestra un rango de dateTime

**Problema**

Mi problema es que desde de sacar el intervalo de las horas, necesito validar que horas esta "available" y las que esten en "false" mostrarlas como un botón desabilitados.

**Esta es la funcion que realiza la petición a la API y llamamos el metodo que filtra el rango horario de los slots (En la variable this.slots seteamos las res):**

```
getAvailability(date: any) {
    this.bookingService.getAffiliateAvailability(this.doctor?.id, this.addressID, date)
      .subscribe(res => {
        if ((this.availableShcedules && this.availableShcedules.length > 0)) {
          this.availability = res;
          const { slots } = this.availability;
          //slots son el arreglo que contiene el rango de horas
          this.slots = slots;
          console.log(slots);
          // metodo que filtra el rango de horas
          this.getSchedulOptions();
          //this.changeDate(slots);
        }
        else {
          this.attentionSchedules
        }
      }, (error => {
        console.error(error)
      }))
  }
```

**Método que se encarga de filtrar e iterar el rango horario que viene en el objeto "start & end"**

```
 getSchedulOptions() {
    let hours: any[] = [];
    this.slots.forEach((s: any) => {
      let start = new Date(s.start);
      let end = new Date(s.end);
      this.available = s.available;
      let range = this.getRange(start, end);
      let filteredRange = range.filter((hourAsDate: Date) => {
        return !hours.some(hour => hourAsDate.getHours() === hour.getHours());
      });
      hours = hours.concat(filteredRange);
    })
    console.log('customRange', hours);
    this.timeList = hours.map(hourAsDate => {
      return moment(hourAsDate).format('h:mm a')
    })
  }
```

**Resultado al aplicar ForEach en el método getSchedulOption (Es un arreglo simple y te vienen todas las horas)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo supongo que no me funciona porque estoy trayendo todas las horas y si yo le paso a getScheduleOption un `if` en donde estoy iterando que diga luego de que me obtengas el rango de horas: Si available = false entonces retorname el boton de la hora desabilitado algo asi:

```
hours = hours.concat(filteredRange);
      if (this.available) {
      }
      else{
        console.log('object', s);
        this.isDisable = true;
        return 
      }
```

**EL objeto de array**

```
[
    {
        "slot": "07:00-08:00",
        "start": "2021-12-23T07:00:00-06:00",
        "end": "2021-12-23T08:00:00-06:00",
        "count": 0,
        "available": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "08:00-09:00",
        "start": "2021-12-23T08:00:00-06:00",
        "end": "2021-12-23T09:00:00-06:00",
        "count": 0,
        "available": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "09:00-10:00",
        "start": "2021-12-23T09:00:00-06:00",
        "end": "2021-12-23T10:00:00-06:00",
        "count": 0,
        "available": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "10:00-11:00",
        "start": "2021-12-23T10:00:00-06:00",
        "end": "2021-12-23T11:00:00-06:00",
        "count": 0,
        "available": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "11:00-12:00",
        "start": "2021-12-23T11:00:00-06:00",
        "end": "2021-12-23T12:00:00-06:00",
        "count": 0,
        "available": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "12:00-13:00",
        "start": "2021-12-23T12:00:00-06:00",
        "end": "2021-12-23T13:00:00-06:00",
        "count": 0,
        "available": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "13:00-14:00",
        "start": "2021-12-23T13:00:00-06:00",
        "end": "2021-12-23T14:00:00-06:00",
        "count": 0,
        "available": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "14:00-15:00",
        "start": "2021-12-23T14:00:00-06:00",
        "end": "2021-12-23T15:00:00-06:00",
        "count": 0,
        "available": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "15:00-16:00",
        "start": "2021-12-23T15:00:00-06:00",
        "end": "2021-12-23T16:00:00-06:00",
        "count": 0,
        "available": true
    }
]
```

Comment: Hola!, puedes poner una muestra más grande de slots? Para hacer un ejemplo funcional.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, ya puse el objeto asi como lo recivo de la API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```javascript
 ngOnInit() {
    this.slotsModificados = this.slots.map((rango) => {
      //Usamos la fecha de inicio para comprobar si el rango actual
      // es valido según la hora actual
      let start = new Date(rango.start);
      //La hora de inicio tiene que ser mayor que la hora actual
      // para que este disponible. 
      rango.available = start > this.horaActual;
      
      //Agrego un nuevo campo al objeto para controlar la clase 
      // que le voy a dar a mi botón(opcional). 
      rango['class'] = rango.available ? 'avaliable' : 'not-avaliable';

      return rango;
    });
  }
```

Usamos `ng-container` para iterar sobre el arreglo. Tu estructura remplazará esta.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let slot of slotsModificados">
  <button [class]="slot.class">{{ slot.slot }}</button>
  <br />
  <br />
</ng-container>
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8rw3jb?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Wow, te has pasado, muchas gracias, nadie se toma el tiempo de explicar. Mil gracias, eres muy amable. Me quedo claro!

Comment: @Izlia Cuando se acota bien el problema es más fácil ayudar.